# Is there a Java API for extracting MP4 metadata?

Tags: java, metadata, mp4

I want to be specific as to what I am asking. I am not asking to modified any MP4 files, just extract metadata such as Width and Height and bitrate and encoding and this is not in the MP3 tags.

I have tested Xuggle which works, but I need to have a library that does not use JNI or any native code.

I already looked into MP4Parser, and Apache Tika, and they both does not extract metadata, just tag info or alter the file.

Is there such java lib?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I actually found what I was looking for using [Mp4Parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser)

here is a simple lines of code to get what I wanted using Mp4Parser

```
FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream("content/Video_720p_Madagascar-3.mp4").getChannel();
IsoFile isoFile = new IsoFile(fc);
MovieBox moov = isoFile.getMovieBox();
for(Box b : moov.getBoxes()) {
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

b contains all the info I needed, now I just have to parse b to get exactly what I want.

Comment: Does IsoFile support FileChannel in the constructor?

Comment: @Mazze [IsoFile no longer supports FileChannel](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/blob/master/isoparser/src/main/java/com/coremedia/iso/IsoFile.java). Update the code to this:  
  
`FileDataSourceImpl fileDataSource = new FileDataSourceImpl("content/Video_720p_Madagascar-3.mp4");  
IsoFile isoFile = new IsoFile(fileDataSource);  `

Comment: @churk How will you handle `UnknownBox` parsing into `Mp4Parser` lib ?

Comment: Remember to close the channel `fc.close()` when you're finished.

Answer (score 1):

At present (2015), Android SDK provides [MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) class for extracting metadata:

```
        MediaMetadataRetriever m = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        m.setDataSource(mInputFile);
        String extractedHeight = m.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
        String extractedWidth = m.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);
```