# Does Android Support Writing the 'Software' Metadata Field in Mp4s?

Tags: android, metadata, mp4

Is there any way to write the 'software' metadata field in mp4's in Android? In the APIs, I see the MediaMetadata class (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadata.html), but it seems this is mainly focused on metadata for music (artist, album, etc...).

In short, I'm looking for the equivalent of AVMetadataCommonKeySoftware over in iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationMetadataKeyReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Common_Metadata_Keys

Answer (score 1):

No. If I understand you right, are you looking to add/modify a metadata tag? Android itself doesn't support modifying mp4 files. [MP4](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/mpeg-4files.html) has a standard place to put metadata, but no standard for what tags to use. It only has a copywrite tag. The mp4 file structure has atoms/boxes and it uses the UTDA sub-box of various other boxes like MOOV for custom data. Some mp4s are written with the ID32 box that contains id3.2 tags. So not all mp4s will be guaranteed to have a software tag or even the same metadata. Apple works with quicktime metadata ('MOOV' box). You can use a java library like [mp4parser](http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/) ( [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679662/is-there-a-java-api-for-extract-mp4-metadata) ) to get the box information, use another library for parsing the tag info for (moov, ID32, ect) and then you would put it back together with your software tag and write it back to the file using mp4parser.

Answer (score 0):

JCodec now provides the API and a CLI tool to add/edit/delete iTunes metadata in MP4 files. Read more about it: http://jcodec.org/docs/working_with_mp4_metadata.html

The CLI is in [org.jcodec.movtool.MetadataEditorMain](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jcodec/movtool/MetadataEditorMain.java) and the API is in [org.jcodec.movtool.MetadataEditor](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jcodec/movtool/MetadataEditor.java).

Here's a usage sample:

```
# Changes the author of the movie
./metaedit -f -si ©ART=New\ value file.mov
```

or the same thing via the Java API:

```
MetadataEditor mediaMeta = MetadataEditor.createFrom(new
    File("file.mp4"));
Map<Integer, MetaValue> meta = mediaMeta.getItunesMeta();
meta.put(0xa9415254, MetaValue.createString("New value")); // fourcc for '©ART'
mediaMeta.save(false); // fast mode is off
```

To convert string to integer fourcc you can use something like:

```
byte[] bytes = "©ART".getBytes("iso8859-1");
int fourcc =
    ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getInt();
```

However if you take a freshly transcoded file and re-add metadata to it the iTunes and QuickTime won't see it (though it will show up in mediainfo). It's a known bug and JCodec team is working on it.